# how do I update an object in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize, and I'm trying to update an object, but it's not working. here is my code

```
const updateEmployee = async (req, res) =>{
    let {full_name, email, phone_number, address} = req.body

    const id = req.params.id;
    Employee.findOne({
        where: { id: id }
    })
        .then(employee => {
            employee.update({
                full_name: full_name.full_name,
                email: email.email,
                phone_number: phone_number.phone_number,
                address: address.address
            })
        })
}
```

please assist !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the update() method and add the search scope as second argument. The update() method is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that returns an array with with one or two elements. The first element is always the number of affected rows. [See the sequelize API documentation for more details on the update() method](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update).

Your code should look something like this. I have not tested this so you might need to tweak the code a bit:

```
updateUser: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await employee.update(req.body, { 
      where: { 
        id: req.body.id 
      } 
    })
    .then((result) => {
      // check the first element in the array if there are rows affected
      if (result[0] > 0) {
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'data found' });
      } else {
        return res.status(422).send({ message: 'no data found' });
      }
    })
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).send({ message: 'updating user failed' });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `async` function. It is best to use await also don't use promise based format this in below api first I am finding user with that id from database if its present it ill update user else it will throw error that there is no data with that id

```
updateUser: async (req, res) => {
    try {

        let data = await employee.findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.body.id
            }
        });
        if (data) {
            await employee.update(req.body, { where: { id: req.body.id } });
            return res.status(200).send({message: data found});
        }
        else {
            return res.status(422).send({message: no data found});
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).send({message: Internal server error);
    };
}
```

Comment: The Answer above did not work for me, id is undefined